# Rspec to skip devise action in controller - sign_in_and_redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, rspec, devise

I have integrated rails application with omniauth and devise integration. In one the controller I have -

```
def create
     # some 
     # stuff 
     # here
   sign_in_and_redirect(:person, @person)
     # some 
     # stuff 
     # here
 end
```

as this action is from devise, i shouldn't be testing this action but only presence of it(correct me here if i am wrong.). Also, as I am mocking this person object, it doesn't have methods to pass origin sign_in_and_redirect action.

So, how can test this controller ?

**UPDATE**

I tried this in my before do block -

```
controller.stub!(:sign_in_and_redirect).and_return(true)
```

But this give me error as - Missing templace authentications/create
I don't have any create.html.erb, as it redirects in normal workflow.

---

**UPDATE**

My AuthencationController#create method code can be seen here - http://www.pastie.org/2116067
My Test code can be seen here - http://www.pastie.org/2116081

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found that it has to do with devise.

This solved issues - devise wiki - [How To: Controllers and Views tests with Rails 3 (and rspec)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29)

I had to include support/devise.rb file and below lines -

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

After that I just added required methods to person class by stubbing it and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

`sign_in_and_redirect` gives you a `MissingTemplate` error because the actual method does a redirect, whereas the stub does not, so Rails assumes you want to render the template.

> i shouldn't be testing this action but only presence of it

You should be specifying how `create` behaves, not what methods it calls internally. This is not the same as mocking the interaction with another component, like the model.

Since you are working backwards (writing the code before the example), I'd recommend starting with an example that does no stubbing or mocking at all and get it to pass. Then you can experiment with stubbing out pieces to get isolation from the model, but there's no benefit in isolating from Devise.